# get content in view from ContentBinding

Tags: view, ember.js

I've got problem with new Ember.js (1.0 pre)

I got something what worked on Ember 0.9.8 but when I changed version of this lib I noticed problem which can't resolve. (I'm not so good at Ember :/)

Here is sample code:
http://jsfiddle.net/ETQCc/5/

I created view:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="MyView">
    {{s}} / {{content.s}} / {{this.s}} / {{view.s}}
</script>

App.myview = Em.View.extend({
    layoutName : "MyView",
});
```

And I'd like to show some varible which depends on what I set in content bindig:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
     xx{{view App.myview contentBinding="App.ctrl"}}
</script>
```

How to get to varible in this controller?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two ways to do that.
You can :

- bind the controller to your view instead of binding the content (see [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wt4fk/)). By doing that you set the context of the view to be the controller, so `{{s}}` works directly:

`{{view App.myview controllerBinding="App.ctrl"}}`

- edit your template to get the variable from the view instead of its context (see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wt4fk/1/)). By doing that the view content is binded to the controller, and your template shows the `s` property of the view content:

`{{view.content.s}}`

I suggest you to take a look at [Ember.js View Context changes](https://gist.github.com/2494968).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer...
I should use:
    {{view.content.s}}