# Sending content to ember-leaflet from a specific controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, leaflet

(Tighter version of the (deleted) question I asked yesterday…)

Trying to get an address (from an `address` model) to appear on an ember-leaflet map when by itself.

This works, proving that the maps are rendering ok (earlier I had a problem since I defined the view before the marker collection layer in `views/map.js`):

```
App.MarkerCollectionLayer = EmberLeaflet.MarkerCollectionLayer.extend({
  content: [
    {location: L.latLng(40.714, -74.000)}
  ]
});

App.MapView = EmberLeaflet.MapView.extend({
  classNames: ['ember-leaflet-map'],
  childLayers: [
    App.TileLayer, // defined elsewhere
    App.MarkerCollectionLayer
  ],
  zoom: 13
});
```

with this controller (`controllers/address.js`):

```
App.AddressesShowController = EmberObjectController.extend({
  someText: "The controller works"
});
```

with this template (`templates/addresses/show.hbs`):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8" id="map">
  {{view App.MapView }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h3>{{someText}}
    <h4>{{street}}</h4>
    <h5>{{city}}, {{state}}, {{postalCode}} <br>
    {{country}}</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

But as soon as I try to move everything to the controller, the marker disappears. I don't even use the `contentBinding: 'controller'` line in defining `MapView`, since I want to reuse it throughout the app. So something as simple as this (`views/map.js`):

```
App.MarkerCollectionLayer = EmberLeaflet.MarkerCollectionLayer.extend({
});
```

`controllers/address.js`:

```
App.AddressesShowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  someText: "The controller works",
  content: [
    {location: L.latLng(40.714, -74.00)}
  ]
});
```

and `templates/addresses/show.hbs` (suggested by [get content in view from ContentBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493693/get-content-in-view-from-contentbinding) ):

```
  <div class="col-md-8" id="map">
    {{view App.MapView contentBinding="App.AddressesShowController"}}
  </div>
```

Makes no marker appear. I think I've more or less exhausted the ways to make sure the ember-leaflet view gets bound to a specific controller. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, with `contentBinding: "controller"` set, this works fine in `addresses.index`, that is, it shows all of the addresses, with no work even for the controller. (I have a computed property on the `address` model called `location` that ember-leaflet picks up). I've tried to define a separate `MarkerLayer` just for a single marker / `ObjectController`, but it, too, does not show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the case that the `MarkerCollectionLayer` is for, surprise, marker collections, while the `MarkerLayer` fits for solitary markers (or whatever might be served up, I suppose, by an `ObjectController` instead of an `ArrayController`.

This layer definition (coupled with adjusting `childLayers` on `MapView`) makes the above example work swimmingly:

```
App.MarkerLayer = EmberLeaflet.MarkerLayer.extend({
  contentBinding: "controller"
});
```

The map gets the content (via the `location` computed property on the `address` model) and shows it. Nothing special needs to be added to the controller.

For completeness, here's the model that shows the location computed property:

```
App.Address = DS.Model.extend({
  street: DS.attr('string'),
  city: DS.attr('string'),
  state: DS.attr('string'),
  postalCode: DS.attr('string'),
  country: DS.attr('string'),
  latitude: DS.attr('number'),
  longitude: DS.attr('number'),
  location: (function() {
    return L.latLng(this.get('latitude'), this.get('longitude'));
  }).property('latitude', 'longitude')
});
```